# Spring Data r2dbc and hibernate reactive: how to configure both using only one source of configuration

Tags: spring-data-r2dbc, hibernate-reactive

I'm usin these two libraries:

- `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc`
- `org.hibernate.reactive:hibernate-reactive-core`

It's not clear to me if I need to configure both `spring.data.url` and `_/src/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml` or only one of them.

- Could I remove `persistence.xml`?
- Could I remove `spring.data.datasource`?
- Can I configure all of them using `persistence.xml` file?

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, Hibernate Reactive only supports the [Vert.x reactive database clients](https://vertx.io/docs/#databases), not R2DBC.

It would, at least in principle, be relatively straightforward to integrate a different reactive database client API with Hibernate Reactive, since Hibernate Reactive was designed for this, and abstracts the interaction with the database client. But AFAIK no-one has tried to do that yet.